# How to write ("some text") within ("")?

Tags: vbscript

Probably an easy question for most of you in here, but I cannot seem to get it right.

How do I make this line of code work?

```
MyFile.WriteLine("Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")")
```

I understand why I get the error with ')' expected, but I just don´t know how to get around it.

The (" and ") wrapping the string Scripting.FileSystemObject is causing the problem.

In other words, I need to WriteLine EXACTLY the following:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Use "" to escape the single double-quote in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-up the `"`...like this:

```
MyFile.WriteLine("Set fso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")")
```

Comment: Thanks aphoria. This is the only way it worked in my VBScript:)